# PHP Array (as xml seen)

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am trying to achieve this output from PHP array.

```html
<Timesheets>
  <Timesheet>
    <EmployeeID>5e493b2e-c3ed-4172-95b2-593438101f76</EmployeeID>
    <StartDate>2013-04-03</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2013-04-10</EndDate>
    <Status>Draft</Status>
    <TimesheetLines>
      <TimesheetLine>
        <EarningsRateID>0daff504-2d42-4243-bdac-24f2bae0ce7c</EarningsRateID>
        <NumberOfUnits>
          <NumberOfUnit>8.00</NumberOfUnit>
          <NumberOfUnit>8.00</NumberOfUnit>
          <NumberOfUnit>8.00</NumberOfUnit>
          <NumberOfUnit>8.00</NumberOfUnit>
          <NumberOfUnit>8.00</NumberOfUnit>
          <NumberOfUnit>0.00</NumberOfUnit>
          <NumberOfUnit>0.00</NumberOfUnit>
        </NumberOfUnits>
      </TimesheetLine>
    </TimesheetLines>
  </Timesheet>
</Timesheets>
```

and my php code is (only array)

```html
        $new_timesheet = array();
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet'] = array();
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['EmployeeID'] = '8534e85a-e398-4041-99b1-cce51e7a8a02';
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['StartDate'] = "2018-01-22";
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['EndDate'] = "2018-01-28";
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['Status'] = "Draft";
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['Hours'] = "5.0";
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['TimesheetLines'] = array();
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['TimesheetLines']['TimesheetLine'] = array();
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['TimesheetLines']['TimesheetLine']['EarningsRateID'] = '0daff504-2d42-4243-bdac-24f2bae0ce7c';
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['TimesheetLines']['TimesheetLine']['NumberOfUnits'] = array();
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['TimesheetLines']['TimesheetLine']['NumberOfUnits'][]['NumberOfUnit'] = array('8.00');
        $new_timesheet['Timesheet']['TimesheetLines']['TimesheetLine']['NumberOfUnits'][]['NumberOfUnit'] = array('9.00');
```

but unexpectedly I am getting this output

```html
<Timesheets>
  <Timesheet>
    <EmployeeID>8534e85a-e398-4041-99b1-cce51e7a8a02</EmployeeID>
    <StartDate>2018-01-22</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2018-01-28</EndDate>
    <Status>Draft</Status>
    <Hours>5.0</Hours>
    <TimesheetLines>
      <TimesheetLine>
        <EarningsRateID>0daff504-2d42-4243-bdac-24f2bae0ce7c</EarningsRateID>
        <NumberOfUnits>
          <NumberOfUnit>8.00</NumberOfUnit>
        </NumberOfUnits>
        <NumberOfUnits>
          <NumberOfUnit>9.00</NumberOfUnit>
        </NumberOfUnits>
      </TimesheetLine>
    </TimesheetLines>
  </Timesheet>
</Timesheets>
```

you can see it is repeating "NumberOfUnits" tag, which is incorrect. 
Output should be as the first one.
can anybody do this for me?

Comment: What's the code making xml from an array?

Comment: `$new_timesheet['Timesheet']['TimesheetLines']['TimesheetLine']['NumberOfUnits']['NumberOfUnit'][] = array('9.00');` ?

Comment: it is xero codegniter library from here 
https://github.com/dharyk/codeigniter-xero
code something like that
 $post_body  = ArrayToXML::toXML($arguments[0], $rootNodeName = $method);
in application/libraries/Xero.php (Line#304)

Comment: that library, seems,  can't to build such xml :( I take desired xml, call toArray function of the library and call toXML with the result - https://eval.in/938760

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you have a `NumberOfUnits` array inside which there are multiple `NumberOfUnit` entries.

You can achieve the desired result by assigning to the `NumberOfUnit` array in the below manner

```
$new_timesheet['Timesheet']['TimesheetLines']['TimesheetLine']['NumberOfUnits']['NumberOfUnit'][] = '8.00';
$new_timesheet['Timesheet']['TimesheetLines']['TimesheetLine']['NumberOfUnits']['NumberOfUnit'][] = '9.00';
```

Comment: @user3099268 ^  Are you sure that the same?